# How to 'scrape away' at a low-poly plane?

Tags: modeling, brushes

I'm trying to figure out if there's some sort of 'boolean brush' that I can use in top-down mode to 'eat away' at the edges of a low-poly plane? I'm trying to achieve a rusted/decayed look. An example of what I mean...[image: What I want to achieve]

Comment: You can't create geometry like that without increasing at least the vertex count resulting in a massive n-gon.  You can fake it by using transparency in a shader, though.

Comment: Hi Marty, I don't mind a vertex count increase. I've been using Bool/Difference to achieve the effect, but I wonder if there's an easier way. I was using a transparency shader before, but was running into tons of issues (I'm using Unity)